# Unexpected token 'export' on Mocha test in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, mocha.js

I have installed a internal npm package which contains `export * from './components;'`
Due to this line the mocha test gives **SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'** I have tried installing the babel packages and added .babelrc file. But none helped me. Below are the packages installed

1. "@babel/cli": "^7.14.8",
2. "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
3. "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
4. "@babel/register": "^7.14.5",
5. "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
6. "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
7. "mocha": "^9.0.3",
8. "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0"

The cmd used to execute mocha test is `"mocha --require @babel/register --require jsdom-global/register --require ts-node-test-register --require=dotenv/config __tests__/**/*test*.ts*"`

The .babelrc file contains

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0","@babel/react-env"],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if there is a missing semicolon? Sounds like there is a missing one before the next "export" statement.